# Woocommerce - Show total weight as quantity increases on archive

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I found a code snippet on [Regiel Gallarde's](https://reigelgallarde.me/programming/show-product-price-times-selected-quantity-on-woocommecre-product-page/) website that displays in a div the total price according to quantity field update. I used this as a base to write a snippet that does the same stuff but with the price and on the archive. I ended up with this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_total_product_weight', 31 );
function woocommerce_total_product_weight() {
    global $woocommerce, $product;
    // let's setup our divs
    echo sprintf('<div id="product_total_weight" style="margin-bottom:20px;">%s %s</div>',__('Peso total:','woocommerce'),'<span class="weight">'.$product->get_weight().'</span>');
    ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(function($){
                const weight = <?php echo $product->get_weight(); ?>
                    /*weight_unit = get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit'),*/

                $('[name=quantity]').change(function(){
                    if (!(this.value < 1)) {

                        const product_total_weight = parseFloat(weight * this.value);

                        $('#product_total_weight .weight').html(product_total_weight.toFixed(2));

                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

It manages to show the weight for each product on the archive page but crashes when I update the quantity selector.

Does anyone know what is wrong with my approach?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: _"quantity increases on archive"_ - by default in WooCommerce you cannot increase/decrease the amount on those types of pages, that is only provided on the single product page. 
And if you got it via extra code/plugin it doesn't seem to me that an ID (#selector) is used since it concerns a loop of products. So please include [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm using the name of the field instead of the id, but yeah it comes from a plugin and the input that generates looks like this: <input type="number" id="quantity_621d9508dc06c" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Cantidad" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric" autocomplete="off">